# Nested Lists in Jquery Content Switcher

Tags: jquery, nested

I am try to figure out how to add nested tabs to this page. Does anyone have any ideas? I have tried a few things, but I cant seem to get it to work.

Ill bet there is a simple solution that I am over looking. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

http://jsfiddle.net/8FxAK/

Comment: I can't really tell what you're looking to do.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/)?

Comment: I would, but they dont let you use the back button. This tabs plugin does and thats what I like about it. Unless you know of a way to make UI tabs do this.